# Custom attribute "data-ccp-props"

Tags: html, attributes

It's ridiculous question,have anyone seen custom attribute "data-ccp-props" in html span tag likes this?

```
<span data-ccp-props="{&quot;201341983&quot;:2,&quot;335559739&quot;:160,&quot;335559740&quot;:233}" style="line-height: 1.4;">&nbsp;</span>
```

I found much similar data by Google [enter link description here](https://tea.texas.gov/sites/default/files/covid/dont-miss-your-shot-email-blast-2.txt), that custom attribute makes an error on our html editor.

Comment: Something similar came to me and I have no idea where it came from:

<span class="EOP SCXW102513011 BCX0" data-ccp-props="{&quot;201341983&quot;:0,&quot;335559739&quot;:0,&quot;335559740&quot;:240}" style="">&nbsp;</span >

Answer (score 0):

Read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*

> The `data-*` global attributes form a class of attributes called custom data attributes, that allow proprietary information to be exchanged between the HTML and its DOM representation by scripts.

So, these are custom attributes given by the site author and *the issue is with your editor* and how it processes them (*or fails to do so*). Nothing wrong with them being in the html.

If they are properly (*as in proper HTML*) set, and i do not see something wrong in your sample code, your editor should be able to handle them.

Comment: hello Gabriele Petrioli. client copy&pasted text on the internet. and 3rd party plugins did not recognized that attribute. So just curious,  I would like to know what "something" used that custom attribute such as chrome dark theme extension.   I saw translate or dark theme extension inject some attributes into html for working